# Hide CMD window of Marlin Miner

Tags: powershell, cmd, bitcoin

I am using Marlin to mine SiaCoin on my home & work computers (Windows 10), but I was wondering if there was a way I could have it mining without showing the CMD window all the time. I figure there must be a way by using a shell script or similar. I have already tried and failed.

Here is the .bat file that I use to run marlin.exe

```
    SET payout_address=166ddc2830466be66485e337a8dc6dcd4cef167d8b51408cbadff601242564530fad3ee54bcc
SET intensity=24
SET pool_server=us-east.luxor.tech:3333

marlin.exe --user %payout_address% --intensity %intensity% --host %pool_server%
```

Answer (score -1):

Name this file `something.vbs`.

```
'False = don't wait, True = wait for program exit
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """c:\folder\marlin.exe"" --user %payout_address% --intensity %intensity% --host %pool_server%", 0, false
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx